# Powershell Script for automatic execution of an .exe file, located in different directories, on the same base directory

Tags: powershell, for-loop, automation, arguments, executable

I am trying to execute an .exe executable file (let' say it is called myfile.exe) under the argument (argument.fst) . Both files have the same name for each execution, but are located in different subfolders in the same parent directory.

My objective is to create a for-loop, in which, I will pinpoint the paths to both files (14 groups in total, so 14 loops) and then Windows Powershell will execute those. My goal is to automate my simulations, ran by the .exe files+arguments, thus saving time.

Is my thought possible to be implemented on Windows Powershell?

Thank you very much,
Ioannis Voultsos.

Comment: What do you mean by "14 groups in total" - groups of _what_? Executables and argument sets?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes indeed. I need to run 14 times the .exe plus the argument sets, so the loop will comprise of 14 repetitions. Thank you for your answer

Comment: yes but is it the same exe and 14 different arguments? Or the same exe and argument repeated 14 times?

Comment: It is the same exe and argument file set, which belong to 14 different directories. Some values of the argument file change for each loop, but the argument file remanis the same. So, what I want to do is to create a script, which searches and executes the .exe and the argument file for 14 paths in total.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automate the process, you may store your command,args in csv file (i.e. commands.csv):

```
command;arguments
myapp.exe;c:/
myapp.exe;h:/
```

then load it and execute using &:

```
$csv=(import-csv commands.csv -delimiter ';')
$csv|foreach{ &$_.command $.arguments }
```

Beware of executing commands from strings, coming from untrusted sources though.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this sample code on the parent folder

```
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {($_.psiscontainer)} | ForEach-Object { cd $_.FullName; & ".\SampleApp.exe args0 args1"; cd.. }
```

it will go into each directory and execute .exe in each folder with arguments.